# Microsoft Graph API 6 Timeouts and Retry settings?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

How to set timeouts and retry settings in Microsoft Graph API 6 ?

It was possible in version 5 by :

```
var httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(tokenCredential(cred)))
    .newBuilder()
    .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(MAX_IDLE_CONNECTIONS, KEEP_ALIVE_DURATION_MINUTES, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
    .connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_DURATION)
    .callTimeout(CALL_TIMEOUT_DURATION)
    .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_DURATION)
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
    .addInterceptor(buildRetryHandlerInterceptor())
    .build();

return GraphServiceClient
    .builder()
    .httpClient(httpClient)
    .buildClient();
```

it looks it isn't possible to inject custom `httpClient` in ver 6

Comment: Such a question is a perfect fit for ChatGPT.

Comment: @JanezKuhar nope, because chatgpt trained on data until September 2021, but graph api v6 was released in December 2023

Comment: I see that version 6.1.0 of `msgraph-sdk-java` has only been released 5 days ago - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/releases. You can take a look at its javadoc JAR (I couldn't find it published [online](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph/6.1.0/index.html) yet)

Answer (score 1):

In version 5, you need to set middleware options at client instantiation.

Since version 6, you can setup retry settings per-request options.

to the default middleware to configure actions like redirects and retries, this can be done using the `requestConfiguration` lambda by adding a `RequestOption` instance to the Options collection.

```
RetryHandlerOption retryHandlerOption = new RetryHandlerOption(...);
graphClient.me().get(requestConfiguration -> {
    requestConfiguration.options.add(retryHandlerOption);
});
```

[Per-request options](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v6.md#per-request-options)

[RetryHandlerOption](https://github.com/microsoft/kiota-java/blob/main/components/http/okHttp/src/main/java/com/microsoft/kiota/http/middleware/options/RetryHandlerOption.java)